# How long is too long for a script?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

Okay so I'm writing this script for a game where I can change the color of the player object. I have preset colors and I have 8 of them. There will be 4 sets of these colors for different aspects of the player object. So in total I will have 32 plus a few other buttons on the page. The script is really simple but just repetitive. I will have over a hundred floats and Textures on this one script. All the buttons are within OnGUI and run every frame. Im not too sure if this will effect the performance drastically since the script is very simple. Is it worth splitting it up into different scripts even though they will all still run every frame?

Comment: In a game with a large number of objects, one trick is to not update them all each frame, but rather a subset.  The end result is that processing is _smoothed_ out over time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience if you keep the actions you are performing each frame simply, there should be a performance hit even if you have 10k presets of Colors. If you are using unity Pro you can just use the profiler to determine the load of the script in question and make changes accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by performing each frame simply?

Comment: I mean the code that you place inside a Update() or OnGUI() method. Any code you place in there will be executed every frame. As long as you keep it relatively free from performance heavy operations like GetComponent<> or GameObject.Find, you should be ok.

Comment: ah okay that good news, its all just button layout really and then just a simple value change on the button execution.

Comment: might I ask you why even use OnGUI and the old system. Why not use the new UI system introduced in 4.6 and above. Its better performance wise and easier to use.

Comment: I keep reading this but I dont really understand the difference, what exactly is the new system?